# Can I undo an automatic rename in Quicken?

Tags: quicken

In Quicken, sometimes a renaming rule incorrectly renames a payee, and I'm wondering if there's a way to access or restore the original name before it was processed by the renaming rules.

Comment: You should be able to just undo the rule being ran in general.

Comment: @Ramhound that does not address my question.  That wouldn't be an "undo", that would be an outright deletion and removal of the rule itself.

Comment: You run the rule either by hand, you can undo the changes to the transactions, easily enough.  Once the original name is changed its lost, you would have to roll back each change, until you got to the transaction that shouldn't have been changed.

Comment: @Ramhound--if you have an answer, please post it as one instead of comments.  However, you seem to be saying that it's easy to undo executed renaming rules, except if they've executed.  You add the exception that you can "roll back each change".  You've essentially answered the question with a simple "yes" and offered no further explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To undo an automatic rename, just right click on the transaction under "accept cleared transactions into register."  Then select revert as shown below:

[image]